# Batsman runs through stumps and wicketkeeper: out or not, and how?

Tags: cricket, officiating

Is a batsman out when during a second run, they return to the wicketkeeper's end and run through the stumps and wicketkeeper, after the keeper had already removed the bails and continued to hold the ball?

Should the batsman be out Hit Wicket, if they were not given out Run Out?

Answer (score 2):

If the wicketkeeper cleanly broke the stumps, then the batsman is out - it doesn't matter what happens next add the ball is dead.

Aside: it certainly can't be hit wicket as that explicitly can only happen when playing a stroke or setting of for a first run.

Aside 2: other than in exceptional circumstances, there's no reason a batsman should be running at the wicket - if a batsman did influence the play by doing so, for example by distracting the wicketkeeper, they would be very much at risk of being given out for obstructing the field.